# How to color edges according to node communities?

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

How can I add color information to edges in a tbl_graph ? I would like to color edges according to the color of the 'to' and 'from' nodes : if both nodes have the same color, then the edge between them should get the same color.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

create_notable('tutte') %>%
activate(nodes) %>%
mutate(group = as.factor(group_louvain())) %>%
ggraph() +
geom_node_point(aes(color=group),size=7) +
geom_edge_link()
```

Answer (score 1):

OK... I've found my answer !

```
g <- create_notable('tutte') %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         group = as.factor(group_louvain()))

g <- g %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  mutate(group_from = .N()$group[from],
         group_to = .N()$group[to]) %>%
  mutate(ge = ifelse( group_from == group_to, group_from, NA))




ggraph(g) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color=group),size=7) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = as.factor(ge)) )
```